# Hibernate order by a column's defined attribute

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say I have a table, Address. Each Address has a City (separate table), that has the attributes id and name. I need to order adresses by using Criteria API, by city name's.

```
Criteria c = sessionCriteria.createCriteria(Address.class);
criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("city").asc();
```

However, this order cities by their id's, though I want to order them by city names. Moreover, I have a much more associations like City, therefore I do not want an hardcoded approach. Can I define a comparator for City class, or tell Hibernate to sort Cities by name in City.hbm.xml?

Comment: @Jens I think Criteria cCity = c..createCriteria("city", "city"); should be used yo add alias and then cCity.addOrder(Property.forName("name").asc();

Comment: @Jens I don't want to hardcode them into the code, because I have like 5 other associations, and I am generating criterias programatically, according to the parameters provided.